# Functions or methods?

Tags: c, naming-conventions, abstract-data-type

If I'm writing abstract data types in C, are the functions written to perform actions on these data types and exposed in the interface (.h files) called *functions*, *methods*, or something yet completely different? I can't seem to find a constructive answer anywhere. Is *method* a C++ specific term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is method a C++ specific term?

A "method" is an object-oriented programming term, and refers to a function that is part of the namespace of an object.  So you can create methods for objects in languages like C++, Java, Objective-C, etc. In C on the otherhand, you still have stand-alone functions, not methods.

Keep in mind that the "official" C++ term for a class method is a "member function", and is described in section 9.3 of the spec.

Answer (score 4):

I've always used "method" as a synonym for "member function", which implies C++ since C has no such thing.

On the other side of the coin however, one might argue that the role of `foo_alter_state` in:

```
struct foo {
  // implementation stuff;
}; 

void foo_alter_state(struct foo *self);
```

*was* still a method operating on `foo`s, albeit free-standing. It's basically OOP in C, but implemented by hand.

This perspective might be particularly true if `struct foo;` was only ever declared in headers, but not defined publicly anywhere.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I say that it's not very useful to get too serious about the distinction.

Answer (score 3):

Methods are functions associated with a class.

Since classes don't exist in C, everything is technically a function.

Answer (score 2):

Method is typically used to describe "functions" that are part of a class in OOP. Functions are just that - functions, not part of a class.

In the .h file I'd call them "function declarations" and in the .c I'd call them "function implementations" ... I'm no expert though, just my .02.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a particularly useful distinction to make, but in general, you'd call them *functions* because the word *method* implies a whole bunch of OOP stuff that C doesn't provide. Like [the following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29):

> Methods have the special property that at runtime, they have access to
>   data stored in an instance of the class (or class instance or class
>   object or object) they are associated with and are thereby able to
>   control the state of the instance.

But I've routinely heard folks who grew up on Java refer to C *functions* as *methods* and I've never once been confused about what they meant. Not even a little bit.

You might, however, want to make the following (loose) distinctions:

- A **procedure** is a block of code that does something
- A **function** is a procedure that associates one or more inputs with an output
- A **method** is a procedure that belongs to some class or an instance of that class

Comment: I'd agree with this in general, although I've seen quite a strong correlation between people who use method/function interchangeably and people who view C as "poor man's Java", so it can make an interesting discussion point.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking a function is an operation that gives an output for a given input. Whereas a method is a function bound to a type. C only has functions, I don't think you think any different.

But if you are implementing an ADT by, for example, putting function pointers in a struct (to functions that take a context pointer to the struct instance), so that you're mimicking an object with methods, then I see no reason to call them "methods implemented as functions".