# Difference between function and method in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, function, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functions or methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069973/functions-or-methods)

I was thinking that they were both the same but I'm reading a book on C++ and I'm not really sure how they are different. Sorry I know this question has been asked but I'm still not really sure if they are different or not. Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: C++ doesn't use the term method. It calls them member functions.

Comment: @Pubby, but to not confuse them further it's commonly accepted that method == member function. OP Functions are a C thing, methods are a C++ thing and are like functions, but operate on a object instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069973/functions-or-methods

Comment: @kenny no that is not a commonly accepted thing. i for example thought that it meant "nonstatic member function" to ppl that use the term.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 'member functions' by 'methods', have a look at [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html)

Member functions are functions declared inside a class.

THe difference between ordinary functions and (non-static) member functions is that non-static member functions take an implicit parameter: the pointer to the object they are being called on (this)

Comment: -1, this is incorrect. a member function is a function that is a member of a class, instead of a member of a namespace. member functions can be static.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Not according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk812w4w.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i am aware that there are people that have a wrong understanding of various terms. however just because some microsoft worker published his wrong understanding doesnt mean that it is correct.

Comment: I'll look some more... There is also the technical difference that static functions don't use a 'this pointer'

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-lit you may be right, although I cannot find any source I trust saying this

Answer (score 1):

The C++ language definition talks about "functions" and "member functions". It does not talk about "methods". So the meaning of "function" and of "member function" is well defined. The meaning of "method" for C++ is whatever you think it means, and it's often used in precisely that way, that is, as a fuzzy term for "something I think I can call", without a precise meaning.